# jQuery scrollto after timed delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this page: http://www.yasyf.com/services.html, in which a video autoplays. I would like to have it so that once the video finishes playing (a set amount of time), the page automatically scrolls down to the text, using a jQuery scrollto with timed delay, but only if the page has not yet been scrolled. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See [here](http://microspino.com/video_end_scroll.html) the example I made for you**.

**MORE INFO**

Depending on the player you're using, a video finished event could be available. You can then attach the scrollTo function to it. You can read more about this event here:

- [YOUTUBE](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_status)
- [FLOWPLAYER](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/events/clip.html)
- [ADOBE](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

If you can, give also a look to [this incredibly useful](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) resource and this [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#mediaevents) about video in HTML5.

**About vid.ly :**
It seems to me that they use an **HTML5 with Flash fallback** player. See [here](http://m.vid.ly/user/) the "how can I use vid.ly" section.

**JS code :**

```
// add a scrollTo method to jQuery
$.fn.scrollTo = function(duration){
  if(duration == null){ duration = 1000; }
  var offset = $(this).offset().top - $(window).height()/2 + $(this).height();
  $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: offset}, duration);
}

// Then when the dom is loaded
$("document").ready(function() {
  //for HTML5 (for flash please see the ADOBE link above.)
  $("video").bind("ended", function() {
    // Log on console just for debug
    console.log("autoplay ended! About to scroll to...");

    // scroll to a div with id="scroll_to_here"
    $('#scroll_to_here').scrollTo();
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm using the built-in embed code from vid.ly , is this possible?

Comment: @user837410 added an example on pastie see the link in my post

Comment: @user837410 I made an example of what you need (your vid.ly movie and  the scroll on video end) with a cross browser player  based on "Video for everybody". See the link in the post.

Comment: Although, I cannot figure out how to apply it to flash!

Answer (score 2):

```
var scrolled = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    scrolled = true;
});

var scroll_timer = setTimeout(function(){

    if(scrolled !== true)
    {
        // scroll to whatever
    }
},10000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've got this and it doesn't seem to be working!

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var scrolled = false;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    scrolled = true;
});

var scroll_timer = setTimeout(function(){

    if(scrolled !== true)
    {
        $.scrollTo('#text');
    }
},10000);
</script>

Comment: Try $(window).scroll() instead

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple script to do that.  I assume scroll / keydown / mouse click to say "the user has interacted with the page, don't auto-scroll."

```
(function() {
  var scrollPage = function() {
    $.scrollTo(xyz);
  };
  var c = setTimeout(scrollPage, 35000);
  $(document.body).bind('scroll mousedown keydown', function() {
    clearTimeout(c);
  });
})();
```

Let me know if this helps.